# The Convergence of a Complex Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ and let $C$ be the circle $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid|z|=R\}$.

'If $\sum a_nz^n$ converges at every point $z$ on $C$, except possibly one, then it converges at all points on $C$.'

Is this statement true or false?

I can disprove that if $\sum a_nz^n$ converges at ONE point on $C$ then it is NOT always true that $\sum a_nz^n$ converges everywhere on $C$ by using the fact that
$$
\sum\frac{z^n}{n}
$$
converges at $-1$ but diverges at $1$ with $|-1|=|1|=1$. But I could not find a clue on the other question. Could someone give me some clue please and I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same example that you gave answers your question: the series

$$\sum \frac{e^{in\theta}}{n}$$
is convergent using Dirichlet's test for every $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$.